# Broadcast array multiplication in Fortran 90/95

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I was wondering that would there be a better (succinct) way to code this in Fortran? I am trying to multiply each column of `a(3, 3)` by each value in `b(3)`. I know in Python there is `np.multiply`, and not sure about Fortran.

```
!!! test.f90
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp=kind(0.d0)
    real(dp) :: a(3, 3)=reshape([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [3, 3]),&
        b(3)=[1, 2, 3]
    integer :: i
    do i = 1, 3
        a(:, i) = a(:, i) * b(i)
    end do
    write(*, *) a
end program test
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
a * SPREAD(b,1,3)
```

will produce the same result as your loop.  I'll leave it to you and to others to judge whether this is more succinct or in any way better than the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is absolutely the "standard" way to do it. And also thanks for your comment too. You are right, that this way of writing it is shorter, but harder to understand. More importantly, it copies the array so may be less efficient. Whether this is a better practice is still under question.

Comment: It likely makes a big difference if the real problem is little `3x3` matrices or much larger ones.

Comment: I'm not sure this is *the standard* way of achieving the ends desired.  It seems to me that loops are still the standard way of doing things in Fortran.  Sometimes rightly, sometimes wrongly.

Answer (score 4):

The do loop can be replaced by a one-liner using FORALL:

```
forall (i=1:3) a(:, i) = a(:, i) * b(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are reusing a particular b frequently you could define:

```
 b(3, 3)=reshape([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3])
```

then you just can do:

```
 a=a*b
```

..